# Cap energy consumption of processes on macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management, energy

Most of us probably already had this situation: One is tight on battery and trying to save as much energy as possible. Then suddenly a process goes wild and drains the battery by 10 or more percent within minutes.

Is it somehow possible to cap the energy a process is allowed to use within a certain time interval?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are probably looking to do is keep the multipliers locked to a low value, and/or disable turbo boost.   The former is probably not feasible given the largely proprietary nature of Apple's environment.  Perhaps someone can correct me.

However there is an [app out there that will turn off turbo boost](https://www.rugarciap.com/turbo-boost-switcher-for-os-x/)

Intel also had a utility to monitor the CPU, not sure if it still works... [see this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97577/view-the-current-clock-speed-of-a-cpu-in-os-x)

Comment: I had a perception that turbo boost is beyond user's control. the intel app you linked *displays* the CPU performance, not control it. At least that's what the answer shows, I have not used it.

Comment: @ankii the first link is a third party utility that disables turboboost